# updateing all Foreign key constraint in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database in sql server 2008 R2 that have many table (over 200) and have many relation betweens tables.
**Delete** rule in most of relations is **No Action**
I need to Update all relation **delete rule** to **Cascade** at once
Because of too many relation in my database I dont want do this one by one
Is there any way ?

Comment: In any moderately complex database, there could be multiple cascade paths which aren't allowed by SQL Server's cascade options - so you'll need to carefully plan which ones actually get turned on (then either leave the rest, or you'll have to implement via a trigger)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Also, in any moderately complex database, there will almost certainly be at least a few foreign keys that shouldn't cascade either updates or deletes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you ALTER a Foreign key constraint, using the SSMS GUI, SQL Server on the background actually drops and recreates the same.

Here is a script, that will generate the SQL for dropping all FKeys and recreating them with `ON UPDATE  CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE` options

Assumption is, all your FKeys are name "FK....."

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Objects TABLE
(
ID int identity(1,1),
TableName sysname,
SchemaName sysname
)

INSERT INTO @Objects (TableName, SchemaName)
    SELECT
        TABLE_NAME,
        CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'FK%' 

DECLARE @min int, @max int,@table sysname,@schema sysname

SELECT @min = 1, @max = MAX(ID) FROM @Objects

WHILE @min <=@max
BEGIN

SELECT
    @table = TableName,@schema = SchemaName FROM @Objects WHERE ID = @min

print '/*Drop Foreign Key Statements for [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + ']*/'
SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '].[' + o.name + '] 
DROP CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name + ']'
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o
        ON fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
    WHERE o.name = @table AND
    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = @schema

    print '/*Create Foreign Key Statements for [' 
+ @schema + '].[' + @table + ']*/'
    SELECT
        'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '].[' + o.name + '] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name + '] FOREIGN KEY ([' + c.name + ']) 
    REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(refob.schema_id) + '].[' + refob.name + ']
([' + refcol.name + '])ON UPDATE  CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE'
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
        ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o
        ON fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id AND
    o.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects refob
    ON fkc.referenced_object_id = refob.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns refcol
    ON fkc.referenced_column_id = refcol.column_id AND
    fkc.referenced_object_id = refcol.object_id
WHERE o.name = @table AND
SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = @schema

SET @min = @min+1
END
```

Hope this helps.

Raj

PS: Setting query output to text helps. Also please read the comment posted on your question. Arbitrarily setting `CASCADE` may not be the right thing to do

Comment: your Query just show command to do.Can you change It to execute ?

Comment: DDL queries need to be reviewed before execution.Can you copy the output and execute in a new query window?